# Big O/ Time Complexity with Exponential Condition

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, big-o

Can anyone teach me how to calculate the time complexity when you have an polynomial as a condition in your for loop? eg.

```
for(i  = 1; i < n^4; i = n * i){
...
}
```

Comment: Try to follow the algorithm in a piece of paper and you will discover how to calculate the time complexity of your algorithm

Comment: I think that qualifies as polynomial, not exponential

Comment: Even better than that; it's constant.

Comment: `n^4` isn't exponentiation in Java, it's bitwise-xor.

Answer (score 5):

Since `i` is multiplied by `n` in each iteration, there would be `4` iterations, and assuming that each iteration does a constant amount of work, the time complexity would be `O(1)`.

In the first iteration `i = 1`.
In the second iteration `i = n`.
In the third iteration `i = n^2`.
In the fourth iteration `i = n^3`.
Then i reaches `n^4` and we exit the loop.

Comment: so when referring to this question, regarding an exponential condition where x^n, does n = the number of iterations?

Comment: @12341234 check how `i` variable increases per iteration. That will help you to define the formula to calculate the O time complexity.

Comment: @12341234 No, the number of iterations is not a function of n. That's why it's constant - O(1).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  thanks i get it. thank you. i rewrote each step/ iteration. #thestruggleisreal

Comment: @Eran just wondering, for the time complexity, can i write it as T(n) = 4 = O(4) since there are 4 iterations? sorry im really unfamiliar with the BigO notations

Comment: @12341234 O(4) is the same as O(1) or O(c) for some constant c. The convention is to write O(1) (similarly, you write O(n) and not O(4*n)).

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [document](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/jauhar/ics202/Unit03_ComplexityAnalysis1.ppt) (last slide):

[image]

Therefore, T(n) is **O(1)**.